# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str' issue

Tags: python, html, django

I am working on a group project for college using django and python, however I am running into an issue.

I am following a newsletters tutorial from a youtube playlist and while he has no errors this is the error I am receiving.

[Here is an image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdd5C.png)

Here is the code.

def newsletter_signup(request):
form = newsletterUserSignUpForm(request.POST or None)

```
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    if newsletterUser.objects.filter(email = instance.email).exists():
        messages.warning(request, 'Your email already exists in our database', 'alert alert-warning alert-dismissible')
    else:
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Your email has been signed up to our Newsletter!', 'alert alert-success alert-dismissible')

    subject = "Thank you for joining our Newsletter"
    from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    to_email = [instance.email]

    with open(settings.BASE_DIR + "/templates/newsletters/sign_up_email.txt") as f:
        sign_up_message = f.read()
    message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject=subject, body=signup_message, from_email = from_email, to_email = to_email)
    html_template = get_template("/templates/newsletters/sign_up_email.html").render()
    message.attach_alternative(html_templae, "text/html")
    message.send()

context = {
    'form': form,
}
template = "newsletters\sign_up.html"
return render(request, template, context)
```

I realise the video may be outdated a tad as its from 2017 so any help would be appreicated.

Comment: `settings.BASE_DIR / 'templates/newsletters/sign_up_email.txt'`.

Comment: This seemed to do the job, cheers Willem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Around [django-3.0](/questions/tagged/django-3.0) the `BASE_DIR` setting started to use a [**`Path`** <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) instead of a simple string, and you can not append a `Path` with a string. You can however use [**`/`** operator <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use) to join the path with a directory or filename, so you can use:

```
with open(settings.BASE_DIR / 'templates/newsletters/sign_up_email.txt') as f:
    # …
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using os.path.join.  This functions builds paths that match your operating system.

```
import os
path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,"/templates/newsletters/sign_up_email.txt")
with open(path) as f:
   # DO STUFF
```